# Safely deleting a row from a matrix

Tags: haskell, types

I have written the following for a simple type-safe linear algebra library

```
data Natural where
    Zero :: Natural
    Succ :: Natural -> Natural

type One   = Succ Zero
type Two   = Succ One
type Three = Succ Two
type Four  = Succ Three

data Vector n e where
  EmptyVector :: Vector Zero e
  (:>)        :: e -> Vector n e -> Vector (Succ n) e

deriving instance Eq e => Eq (Vector n e)
deriving instance Show e => Show (Vector n e)

infixr :>

data Matrix r c e where
  EmptyMatrix :: Matrix Zero c e
  (:/)        :: Vector c e -> Matrix r c e -> Matrix (Succ r) c e

deriving instance Eq e => Eq (Matrix r c e)
deriving instance Show e => Show (Matrix r c e)

infixr :/
```

I am now attempting to implement the function

```
dropRow :: Int -> Matrix r c e -> Matrix r c e
```

However, even my partial implementations start throwing errors when the return value of the matrix has a different number of rows

```
dropRow i m | i <= 0  = m
dropRow _ EmptyMatrix = EmptyMatrix
```

Is there any way to keep my types and still implement this function? How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you've given for `dropRow` doesn't really make sense if it's supposed to remove a row from the matrix. This one seems better:

```
dropRow :: Int -> Matrix (Succ r) c e -> Matrix r c e
```

Given that, you can't really have a case that leaves the matrix unchanged, so let's make that an error instead:

```
dropRow i m | i < 0 = error "invalid row number"
```

Then the `0` case is fairly easy:

```
dropRow 0 (_ :/ m) = m
```

The `n+1` case is a bit harder as there's no guarantee that the "tail" of a non-empty matrix is also non-empty, so we need to split out the case of a single row matrix from the case where it has two or more rows:

```
dropRow i (v :/ EmptyMatrix) = error "invalid row number"
dropRow i (v :/ m@(_ :/ _)) = v :/ dropRow (i-1) m
```

Note that `dropRow` is statically unable to take an empty matrix.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I didn't know I had to account for the two `n+1` cases, but that makes sense.

Comment: I didn't realise it either until I stared at the type error for a bit :-)